# Imagemagick: Can I set a max height of the watermark image?

Tags: images, imagemagick

I have this BASH script, which scales the watermark image:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which file to watermark?"

read -e "filetowatermark"

echo "Which file to use as watermark?"

read -e "watermarkfile"

convert "$filetowatermark" "$watermarkfile" +distort affine "0,0 0,0 %[w],%[h] %[fx:t?v.w*(u.h/v.h*0.05):s.w],%[fx:t?v.h*(u.h/v.h*0.05):s.h]" -shave 1 -gravity southeast -geometry +200+200 -compose hard-light -composite "$filetowatermark"-signed.png
```

The script is based on this: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=34883.

Is there a way to give the watermark image a maximum size, for instance a height of 40 px?

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure that watermark file is not larger than 40px by first converting watermark file and then using the resized one.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which file to watermark?"

read -e "filetowatermark"

echo "Which file to use as watermark?"

read -e "watermarkfile"

convert "$watermarkfile" -resize 40x200\> "small$watermarkfile" 

convert "$filetowatermark" "small$watermarkfile" +distort affine "0,0 0,0 %[w],%[h] %[fx:t?v.w*(u.h/v.h*0.05):s.w],%[fx:t?v.h*(u.h/v.h*0.05):s.h]" -shave 1 -gravity southeast -geometry +200+200 -compose hard-light -composite "$filetowatermark"-signed.png

rm "small$watermarkfile"
```

I did not test the script. The changes are:

- watermark file is resized
- resized watermark is used
- resized watermark is deleted afterwards

I found a solution for resizing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007722/resize-with-imagemagick-with-a-maximal-width-height